# how do I use aws secret manager with nodejs lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I tried to wrap the example code snippet to get secrets in a function and then call it but it does not appear to be working. I suspect I am calling it asynchronously and I need to call it synchronously? I just want a function I can call to get a secret value and put it in a var.

this is the function:

```
//outside exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
function getSecret(secretName) {
  // Load the AWS SDK
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
      region = process.env.AWS_REGION,
      secretName = secretName,
      secret,
      decodedBinarySecret;

  // Create a Secrets Manager client
  var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
      region: region
  });

  // In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
  // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
  // We rethrow the exception by default.

  client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
              // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
              // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
              throw err;
          else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
              // An error occurred on the server side.
              // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
              throw err;
          else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
              // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
              // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
              throw err;
          else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
              // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
              // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
              throw err;
          else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
              // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
              // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
              throw err;
      }
      else {
          // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
          // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
          if ('SecretString' in data) {
              return data.SecretString;
          } else {
              let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
              return buff.toString('ascii');
          }
    }
  });
}
```

Then I call it

```
// inside exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var secret = getSecret('mySecret')
console.log('mysecret: ' + secret )
```

The secret var is always `undefined`

EDIT: Async only works with promises so I had to make my function async and return a promise:

```
async function mySecrets(secretName) {
    // Load the AWS SDK
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
        region = process.env.AWS_REGION,
        secretName = secretName,
        secret,
        decodedBinarySecret;

    // Create a Secrets Manager client
    var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
        region: region
    });

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {

            // In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
            // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
            // We rethrow the exception by default.
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
                // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
                if ('SecretString' in data) {
                    resolve(data.SecretString);
                } else {
                    let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                    resolve(buff.toString('ascii'));
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

.....
// inside handler
exports.handler = async (event) => {
....
var value = await mySecrets('mysecret')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need **wait** for the async call to finish.

Inside your main handler you will have something like:

```
// inside your main handler
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
    var secret = await getSecret('mySecret')
    console.log('mysecret: ' + secret )

    return ...
    }
```

Comment: Could I also user a promise instead somehow?

Comment: yep asyc or promises same same.

Comment: @iwaduarte could you please provide complete code with async and await. where i can provide SecretString and other required param dynamically

Comment: The code is complete. If you need additional help you should create a new question and put the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980785/retrieve-secrets-from-aws-secrets-manager-in-node-js

Comment: This is bad practice, awaiting for secret manager in the handler means, awaiting for it in every lambda call, which is not what you need, especially when you use the secrets for the db client which you need to initiate outside the handler.

Comment: Why is that bad practice ? I fail to see how would do otherwise. The idea is to remove secrets from within application. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html.

If could share the reasons as to why is a bad practice. I would be glad.

Answer (score 12):

There is a one more easier way to read from secret manager it.

```
let secretManager = new SecretsManager({ region: 'region-name' });
const data = await secretManager.getSecretValue({ SecretId: 'secretid' }).promise();
console.log(`data is: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
```

Comment: No idea, why the answers above did not work for me and why there multiple articles with much more complex solutions to this problem but thank you. This is the first solution to work for me :)

Comment: Thanks @Dennix, you made my day.

Comment: Worked for me , only thing I had to do is add 'AWS.' in front of SecretManger as follows:
let secretManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({ region: 'region-name' });

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more simple example if someone will need to resolve this issue:

```
const result = await client
  .getSecretValue({
    SecretId: AWSConfig.secretName,
  })
  .promise();

const parsedResult = JSON.parse(result.SecretString);
```

Comment: after two days of countless tries to make this work ==> this did the trick!

Comment: perfect! I think everyone looks for the shorter method straight away.

Answer (score 5):

The `aws-sdk` provides two means of getting values back from APIs. You can use the native callback mechanism, as shown above, or you can, instead, use `.promise()` on the end of the call chain, to convert the API call to its promise equivalent.

E.g.

```js
const data = await secretManager.getSecret({ SecretId }).promise();
```

If you're using `await` then your function needs to be `async` as do all the functions calling it, unless they choose to use Promise's `then`/`catch` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Synchronous solution which you can find here: https://github.com/jwerre/secrets

With this package you can load all your secrets inside of a particular namespace like so:

```js
const config = require('@jwerre/secrets').configSync({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    env: 'production',
    namespace: 'my-namespace',
});
```

This will retrieve all your secrets which may not be exactly what you want. If you want a single secret you can do it like this:

```js
const config = require('@jwerre/secrets').secretSync({
    region: 'us-west-2'
    id: '/my-co/apis/'
});
```

Comment: what is /my-co/apis is it  secret name?

Comment: Yes indeed. I use slashed for my secrets so I can separate them for different kinds of deployment. For example `/production/lambda1/mysql/username` or `/staging/api/config/aws/secrete`. Checkout the documentation in the readme.

Answer (score 1):

A much better way is to do this inside your async lambda function

Example `key:val => password:rootPassword`

```
const secret = await secretClient.getSecretValue({SecretId: 'SecretKeyName'}).promise().then((data) => {
        return JSON.parse(data.SecretString);
})
```

and then access it as `secret.password`.

**Note**: wrap around `try/catch` block to handle errors automatically.